# JsReport in Docker not display footer

Tags: c#, asp.net, jsreport

I'm using JsReport on .net Core 2.1

As I uploaded it to Azure, it needed to run separately in a Docker container.
https://jsreport.net/learn/dotnet-local#azure-web-apps

however the Footer that showed the pages no longer works.

```
<div>Page<span class="pageNumber"></span>&nbsp;of&nbsp;<span class="totalPages"></span></div>
```

From what I saw, I need to configure this on the server (JsReport Studio), but in this case I just want the footer, since I couldn't store the skeleton of the page, etc.

Is there any solution?

> Everything else works wonderfully, but something essential for me is
> the number of pages. If there is any other way to get around this
> limitation.

Answer (score 0):

The native chrome header/footer documentation is here
https://jsreport.net/learn/chrome-pdf#native-headers-and-footers

Translated into c# asp.net core controller it should look like this.
You need to make sure there is a space for the footer with a margin. And also set an explicit font size because of the chrome scaling issue mentioned in the docs.

```cs
[MiddlewareFilter(typeof(JsReportPipeline))]
public IActionResult Invoice()
{
    HttpContext
        .JsReportFeature()
        .Recipe(Recipe.ChromePdf)
        .Configure(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.Template.Chrome = new Chrome
            {
                DisplayHeaderFooter = true,
                MarginBottom = "2cm",
                FooterTemplate = "<div style='font-size: 20px; '>Page<span class='pageNumber'></span>&nbsp;of&nbsp;<span class='totalPages'></span></div>"
            };
        });

    return View(InvoiceModel.Example());
}
```